# Sencha Touch Native IOS Scroll Issue

Tags: ios, extjs, touch, sencha-touch, native-code

when the List is Dragged vertically to scroll and continues off the top of the screen, the scroll bar gets stuck until the user taps on the list again.

Comment: Are you getting this issue while in mobile devices or desktop browser?

Comment: Only in the IOS Mobile  (After Native Build).